# Loading weights in TH format when keras is set to TF format

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have Keras' `image_dim_ordering` property set to 'tf', so I define my models as this:

```js
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
```

But when I call `load_weights` method, it crashes because my model was saved using "th" format:

```
Exception: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 3, 64) not compatible with provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3)
```

How can I load these weights and automatically transpose them to fix Tensorflow's format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I asked Francois Chollet about this (he doesn't have an SO account) and he kindly passed along this reply:

---

"th" format means that the convolutional kernels will have the shape (depth, input_depth, rows, cols)

"tf" format means that the convolutional kernels will have the shape (rows, cols, input_depth, depth)

Therefore you can convert from the former to the later via `np.transpose(x, (2, 3, 1, 0))` where x is the value of the convolution kernel.

Here's some code to do the conversion:

```
from keras import backend as K

K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

# build model in TH mode, as th_model
th_model = ...
# load weights that were saved in TH mode into th_model
th_model.load_weights(...)

K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

# build model in TF mode, as tf_model
tf_model = ...

# transfer weights from th_model to tf_model
for th_layer, tf_layer in zip(th_model.layers, tf_model.layers):
   if th_layer.__class__.__name__ == 'Convolution2D':
      kernel, bias = layer.get_weights()
      kernel = np.transpose(kernel, (2, 3, 1, 0))
      tf_layer.set_weights([kernel, bias])
  else:
      tf_layer.set_weights(tf_layer.get_weights())
```

In case the model contains Dense layers downstream of the Convolution2D layers, then the weight matrix of the first Dense layer would need to be shuffled as well.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case now. Both Theano and TensorFlow have identical shapes of weights. When converting from `Th` to `TF` (or vice-versa), we have to flip the dimension 1 and 2 (i.e. `input-depth` and `depth`). Do you know why is it so? If you wish to look at kernel_conversion function from Th to TF (or reverse), look [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/conv_utils.py#L67-L87).

Comment: @Pete Warden Dose input_depth means channels and depth means batch size?

Answer (score 0):

You can [Use This Script](https://github.com/titu1994/Keras-Classification-Models) which auto translates theano/tensorflow backend trained model weights directly into the other 3 possible combinations of backend / dim ordering.