# Visualizing the inputs to convolution neural networks using keras and tensorflow as backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

There is an in-detailed post on [keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html).
But when compiling the code I get the error as follows:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visulaize_cifar.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 332, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 635, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 166, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py", line 160, in call
    dim_ordering=self.dim_ordering)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py", line 210, in _pooling_function
    pool_mode='max')
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2866, in pool2d
    x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, pool_size, strides, padding=padding)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1617, in max_pool
    name=name)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 1598, in _max_pool
    data_format=data_format, name=name)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2242, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1617, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1568, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'MaxPool_1' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [1,1,64,128].
```

This error goes when I set `dim_ordering='th'`.
But as I am using tensorflow backend so dimension ordering should be `dim_ordering='tf'`.
Even after setting dim_ordering as 'th', I get error while `loading weights` from `vgg16_weights.h5` as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "visulaize_cifar.py", line 67, in <module>
    model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)
File "/home/dude_perf3ct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 985, in set_weights
    'provided weight shape ' + str(w.shape))
ValueError: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 128, 64) not compatible with provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3).
```

As detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547279/loading-weights-in-th-format-when-keras-is-set-to-tf-format) about 'th' and 'tf'.
 The above error implies layer weights are in 'tf' (but I set it to 'th' to avoid first error) and provided weight shape in 'th' ordering.
`What seems to be the error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question was pretty simple. As, I was using `tensorflow` as backend. So, to convert I inserted the line 
`if K.backend()=='tensorflow':
    K.set_image_dim_ordering("th")`
after `from keras import backend as K`.
This is because the `vgg16_weights.h5` has `th` format and also `cifar10.load_data()`.